Ratio between data in ApexChart bar is too great making small bars impossible to see and to hit. How to resolve?
I have the following ApexChart bar:
var ivaAnnualeOption = {
series: [{
    name: 'Saldo IVA',
    data: [3500, -53, -30000, -1000, -2000, 1500, 500, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}],
chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    height: 350
},
plotOptions: {
    bar: {
        colors: {
            ranges: [{
                from: -Infinity,
                to: 0,
                color: '#FFD8C8'
            }, {
                from: 0,
                to: +Infinity,
                color: '#E1FEEF'
            }]
        },
        columnWidth: '60%',
    }
},
dataLabels: {
    enabled: false,
},
yaxis: {
    title: {
        text: '',
    },
    labels: {
        formatter: function (val) {
            return italianNumberFormatter(val) + '€';
        }
    }
},
xaxis: {
    type: 'string',
    categories: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic"],
    labels: {
        rotate: -90
    }
}
};

var ivaAnnualeChart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#ivaAnnuale"), ivaAnnualeOption);
ivaAnnualeChart.render();

As you can see, Febrary has a value which in proportion to the others is smaller. The users seem unable to identify the data associated to this month, in fact, it seems very difficult to show the tooltip as the mouse has to hover just a few pixel in order to be able to see it.

I'd like either a minimum height or to be able to see the tooltip when the mouse is around the bar. I tried to resolve the latter with
tooltip: {
   intersect: true
}

but it does not resolve the issue.

You can try setting distributed:true in plotOptions, which will make each bar a single-series data. See docs, and an example.
var ivaAnnualeOption = {
  // other configs...
  plotOptions: {
        bar: {
          distributed: true, // <== THIS
          ...
        },
  }
}

